# Is anyone aware of two-factor authentication APIs for Symfony 3 built applications?

Tags: symfony, php-7, symfony-2.3, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Is anyone aware of implementation two-factor authentication for Symfony 3?
I looked at some soft tokens from Google-Authenticators or Authy, hard tokens Yubico or sms verifications but struggling to find answer if those are compatible with Symfony 3... 
Any Guidance please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are existing bundle to do that with Symfony:

- https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle (support symfony 4)
- https://github.com/sonata-project/GoogleAuthenticator

Comment: To understand what happens in two-factor-bundle you can also read this article: https://www.christianscheb.de/archives/14

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

A quick Google landed me on this library for [Authy with Symfony 2/3](https://github.com/grizzlylab/authy-bundle) (though it looks like it's only had one commit).

Ultimately Authy is a REST API that you can call from your controller using the [Authy library for PHP](https://github.com/authy/authy-php). And while it's not Symfony, there is a tutorial showing how you'd [implement two factor authentication using Authy and Laravel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/account-verification-php-laravel) which might help.

Hope this helps!